# Dynamic content url

Tags: jquery, css, less

I want to loop SPAN string values from class .metric-type, so that the string (for ex: "Home-Icon") can be used as the definition of @iconurl to be passed as a parameter to the last declaration. Essentially updating all those spans content url by concatenating matched string. Any ideas?

```
<span class="metric-type">Home-Icon</span>

@iconurl:"";

.iconStyle(@iconurl){
    content:url("/location/@{iconurl}.svg");
}
.metric-type{
   .iconStyle(@iconurl);
}
```

UPDATE:
I was able to achieve some dynamic function by use of `content: attr(data-name)`
but it is very limited and was only able to get a string result as I am not able to concatenate it with additional string variables to generate images.

Although I am editing visual content here, the language just does not support it, so I went with an all jQuery solution here:

```
$('.metric-type').each(function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
            var metricName= $(this).html();
$(this).html("<img src='/filelocation"+metricName+".svg'>"+metricName);
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you wanting to get a value from HTML into LESS/CSS?  That's not really how HTML/CSS works.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. As the variable `@iconurl` is defined before maybe you are trying to use a default value for a mixin parameter. You could achieve that by simple assign the deault value like `.iconStyle(@url: @iconurl) { content: url("/location/@{url}.svg"); }`. You could take a look at the [docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-mixins-parametric-feature);

Comment: I've edited my original question, to make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (via jQuery instead): I was able to achieve some dynamic function by use of `content: attr(data-name)` but it is very limited and was only able to get a string result as I am not able to concatenate it with additional string variables to generate images.

Although I am editing visual content here, the language just does not support it, so I went with an all jQuery solution here:

```
$('.metric-type').each(function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
            var metricName= $(this).html();
$(this).html("<img src='/filelocation"+metricName+".svg'>"+metricName);
        });
});
```